# Magento 2 Templates: How `$block` is assign in template?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml

Can you please tell me where the assignment of the `$block` variable to the template occurs?

```
\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render()
```

I found :

```
 $tmpBlock = $this->_currentBlock;
 $this->_currentBlock = $block;
 extract($dictionary, EXTR_SKIP);
 include $fileName;
 $this->_currentBlock = $tmpBlock;
```

But I don’t understand how the $block variable gets into the current symbol table? From where is `$block` taken in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see, the $block was initialized when they call render() function. Example:

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:252

```
$html = $templateEngine->render($this->templateContext, $fileName, $this->_viewVars);
```

**$this->templateContext** is the $block that will be used on the template file

This is pure PHP feature, for more clearly, I created a test.php and template.php

> 1. test.php

```
<?php

class Block
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo '1+++';
    }
}


class Test
{
    function render($block, $file, $directory)
    {
        include $file;
    }
}

$block = new Block();

$test = new Test();
$test->render($block, 'template.php', []);
```

> 2. template.php

```
<?php

echo $block->test();
```

> 3. My screen result:

```
1+++
```

You can see, I can use $block variable on template.php because I initialized it before including